# C++:: Template functions- Get address of object from object.function

Tags: c++, function, templates, object, lambda

I want to avoid having two parameters. So we have:

```
class A;
void A::boo();
```

I want to turn this code:

```
template <class C>
void foo(C &c, void (C::*func)())
{
    (c.*func)();
}

A a;
foo(a, &a.boo);
```

To this:

```
template <class C, C &c>      // Something similar
void foo(void (C::*func)())
{
    (c.*func)();
}

A a;
foo(&a.boo);                   // Since I'm using the reference of the object instance
```

I believe I understand that templates in C++ are simple string replacing, but I observe that the implementations of them are slightly more advanced and flexible. I also believe I grasp the concept of classes and their member functions; one address in memory for the function and the class instance being like a parameter to the function in order to access the members in memory for that class instance.

So, getting that out of the way, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

EDIT:

My bad, missed the & sign. Correction: &a.boo

Comment: C++ templates are nowhere close to simple string replacing. Where should `foo` get `c` from in your example? Do you expect to pass it as a template argument?

Comment: And `foo(a, a.boo)` shouldn't compile. Did you mean `foo(a, &A::boo)`?

Comment: C++ is sometimes cumbersome: You need both, the object and the member function pointer, always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way C++ works. When you pass a function, you really pass its address. So if `A::foo` is static or non virtual, its address is the same for all objects of class (and subclasses of) A.

Even if it is virtual, you will have one instance of `foo` per subclass, and two different objects of same subclass will have same address for `foo`.

That means that even if you write `a.foo`, at run time there is no way to find what objet you used: all reference to `a` is gone.

The only possible way - but note I'm **not** advising to use it, because of possible corner cases - would be to use macros because they are executed at compile time. Something like

```
#define FOO(a,b) foo(a, a.b)
```

could allow to keep a reference to the object that was given at compile time.

TL/DR: C++ does not support Python syntax for bound methods...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to accept a functor which will *bind* the instance to the call:

```
template <class F>
void foo(F f)
{
    f();
}

A a;
foo( [&a](){ a.boo(); } );
```

Or, without a lambda:

```
A a;
foo(std::bind(&A::boo, &a));
```